# Google oauth2 returns no id_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I seem to miss something with oauth2. I get the `access_token` but not `id_token`!

I use the following to gain a google access_token by passing a "code" granted to me from `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`

```
$oauth2token_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
$clienttoken_post = array(
    "code" => $code,
    "client_id" => $client_id,
    "client_secret" => $client_secret,
    "redirect_uri" => $redirect_uri,
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code"
);

$curl = curl_init($oauth2token_url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clienttoken_post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($json_response);
```

Everything seems to work but according to Google's documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#exchangecode I should be getting `access_token, id_token, expires_in, token_type` which I do except for the `id_token`

`var_dump($json_response);` shows the following:

```
string(126) "{ "access_token" : "ya29.AHES6ZSGlHVW9qA23xs8bHBP578Ef8S5cntJIcPT_SHWA", "token_type" : "Bearer", "expires_in" : 3598 }
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At the token endpoint an id_token is issued only if certain scopes are present, the documentation should clarify that.

It is issued only if the email, profile or OpenID Connect scopes were used. An id_token does not make sense otherwise.

Comment: thanks a lot man. i've been pulling hair for days in here trying to figure out how to get an id_token. I'll include the email scope and hope it does the trick.

Comment: @Kal accepting and then upvoting the answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: You saved my life!  Thank you!

Comment: As of 2021-03-30, the `scopes=["openid", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",]` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add **id_token** for **response_type**.
Then you need to check scopes.
And don't forget that for implicit flow **nonce** param is required.

For more information and example you can check:
http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitAuthRequest